# Beautiful core data object id

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My object from app, syncronize with server every 5 min. And user can check his items in web. I generate for him the following link:

```
"http://mydomain/items/\(self.appDelegate.UUID.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!)/\(items.objectID.URIRepresentation().absoluteString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!)"
```

`UUID` - this is device or icloud key.

So the link looks like:

http://mydomain/items/15FDA6B3-C51A-4057-8F98-0143981CC5C8/x-coredata://60DD8665-3136-4CF0-9FD3-FF9164FC7327/Items/p1

But can i cut `x-coredata://60DD8665-3136-4CF0-9FD3-FF9164FC7327` to this: `/Items/p1`. Does it will be unique ?

Or any other ideas how to make look better item id.

Comment: obviously you can lean on your object's id (if they are uniquely) and don't expose internal core data IDs

Comment: why don't you create your own id and assign a new one to each instance you create?

Comment: Indeed, NSManagedObject's objectID is subject to change if it's not yet been persisted by saving the context in which it was created. Rely on your own identifier property rather than Core Data's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes maybe better create own id, but i found another solution:

```
let id = Item.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString.components(separatedBy: "/p")[1]
```

And result will be integer value.